# Why transform.eulerAngles doesn't rotate my player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a little problem with this game i'm working in, the problem is that the player object isn't rotating with the code i'm using, and it used to work before, idk why, it was working well and i tested several times it's very simple here is the code.

Edit. I just posted the all code of the controller

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed;
    public float runSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;
    private float moveInput;
    private Vector3 rotation;

    public bool isGrounded;
    private bool isAlsoTrampoline;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private Animator animator;

    private float jumpTimeCounter;
    public float jumpTime;

    private bool isJumping;

    private int cState = 1;
    private int capsState = 1;

    public bool isWalking;
    public bool isRunning;
    public bool isCrunching;
    public bool isSliding;
    public bool isGraping;
    public Vector3 climbPos;

    private PortalDetector portalName;
    private Transform otherPortal;
    private int colorPortal = 0;
    private GameObject otherPortalPos;

    private Vector2 currentY,lastY;

    private AudioSource audioStep;

    private bool amFalling;

    public void Step()
    {
        audioStep.Play();
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.tag == "Trampoline")
        {
            isAlsoTrampoline = true;
        }

        if (collision.tag == "Ledge")
        {

            Debug.Log("Puedo Trepar esto!!??? ");
            if (!isGrounded)
            {
                isGraping = true;
                rb.gravityScale = 0;
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
                animator.SetBool("isLedge", true);
                climbPos = GetComponent<Transform>().position;
                Debug.Log("Trepado!!!!!:DDDDD");
            }
        }
        if (collision.tag == "BluePortal")
        {
            colorPortal = 1;            
        }
        else if (collision.tag == "OrangePortal")
        {
            colorPortal = 2;
        }

        if (collision.tag == "Transporter")
        {
            if (colorPortal == 1)
            {
                otherPortal = collision.gameObject.transform.GetChild(3);
            }

            if (colorPortal == 2)
            {
                otherPortal = collision.gameObject.transform.GetChild(2);
            }            
            otherPortalPos = otherPortal.transform.gameObject;            
            transform.position = new Vector3(otherPortalPos.transform.position.x, otherPortalPos.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    void BackToIdle()
    {        
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(climbPos.x+5,climbPos.y,climbPos.z);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 10;
        animator.SetBool("isLedge", false);
        isGraping = false;
    }
    void ClimbingStepOne()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(climbPos.x, climbPos.y + 5, climbPos.z);
    }
    void Start()
    {
        portalName = GetComponent<PortalDetector>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        audioStep = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        currentY = lastY;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (isGrounded && !isGraping)
        {
            if (isWalking)
            {
                moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            }

            if (isCrunching)
            {
                moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * (speed - 1), rb.velocity.y);           
            }

        }

        if (isRunning && !isCrunching && !isGraping)
        {
            moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * runSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        if (isRunning && isSliding && !isGraping)
        {
            moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * runSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

    }

    void Update()
    {


        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
        currentY = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && isGraping)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isClimbing", true);
        }
        if (!isGrounded && isAlsoTrampoline)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", true);
        }
        else
        {
            isAlsoTrampoline = false;
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.CapsLock) && !isCrunching)
        {
            capsState *= -1;
            if (capsState < 0 && moveInput == 0)
            {
                isWalking = false;
                isRunning = true;
                jumpForce = 14f;
            }
            else if(capsState > 0 && moveInput == 0)
            {
                isWalking = true;
                isRunning = false;
                jumpForce = 7f;
            }
            else if (capsState < 0 && moveInput != 0)
            {
                isWalking = false;
                isRunning = true;
                animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
                animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                jumpForce = 14f;
            }
            else if (capsState > 0 && moveInput != 0)
            {
                isWalking = true;
                isRunning = false;
                animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
                animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);
                jumpForce = 7f;
            }

        }        

        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (moveInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
        }

        if (moveInput == 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
            animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);

        }
        else
        {
            if (isWalking)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);
            }
            if (isRunning)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
            }

        }

        if(isGrounded && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.C))
        {
            cState *= -1;
            if (isRunning)
            {                
                if (cState < 0)
                {
                    StartCoroutine (IsSliding());
                    cState *= -1;
                }
                else if (cState > 0)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(IsSliding());

                    cState *= -1;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                isRunning = false;
                isWalking = true;
                if (cState < 0)
                {
                    animator.SetBool("isCrunching", true);
                    isCrunching = true;
                }
                else if (cState > 0)
                {
                    animator.SetBool("isCrunching", false);
                    isCrunching = false;
                }
            }

        }

        if (isGrounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
            animator.SetTrigger("takeOf");
        }

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            animator.SetBool("onGround", true);
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
            amFalling = false;
        }
        else
        {            
            if ((currentY.y < lastY.y - 2) && amFalling == false)
            {
                lastY = currentY;
                animator.SetBool("isFalling", true);
                amFalling = true;
            }
            animator.SetBool("onGround", false);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == true)
        {
            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
                isJumping = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IsSliding()
    {

        isSliding = true;
        isRunning = true;
        isWalking = false;
        animator.SetBool("isCrunching", true);
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(.5f);
        animator.SetBool("isCrunching", false);
        animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        isSliding = false;
    }

}
```

i just made a debug.log and this is the result

Move Input Val:1 Moving right, eulerAngle:(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)rotation:(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:210)

Move Input Val:-1 Moving left, eulerAngle: (0.0, 180.0, 0.0)rotation:(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
PlayerController:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:215)

Comment: Are you sure moveInput stores a correct value? Why don't you add a debug output to it?

Comment: i did it, when i press the left arrow the log panel print the corresponding message also if i press the right arrow, idk what is happening it was working this morning, i just made some animations, but i didn't modified or erased any line of code.

Comment: Not enough information to reproduce, voting to close. Please include a [mre].

Comment: ok give me a second i'll post all the code

Comment: @JoséTimaure Looks like it should work to me. Do you get the same problem if you start with a blank project and attach only this script to an object?

Comment: mm i'm gonna try that i cannot just make it work, thanks for the reply

Comment: My little cousin, she is 4 years old, was in my computer yesterday, i think she did something that just ruin my controller, but it was something else, i created an new object in the same scene and in the same project and it flips correctly, i think i just have to set up the player again, i don't know what she just did, thanks for your answer again.

Comment: Hello, i did what you say, but the problem wasn't the controller, the problem was 4 animations i made, somehow they bug the flip in the player, i just deleted those animations, problem solved, thanks for your help :D